# "Ensure Event Failed" error occur

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomCalc">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">

                    <TextBlock Text="welcome" Height="50" Width="150" MouseDown=""/>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the above program, (in the program i workout in custom control library)
I am trying to change the control textblock => button.(textblock act as button functionality) 
so i try to add a event to the textblock it gives a error message "ensure event failed",
And this file name is "Generic.xaml" so i add a class "Generic.xaml.cs" but same error is show on.
Please explain why it should occur and how to resolve it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a `x:Class` attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file. So your `Generic.xaml` should look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomCalc"
    x:Class="CustomCalc.Generic">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <TextBlock Text="welcome" Height="50" Width="150" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And as for the `Generic.xaml.cs` :

```
namespace CustomCalc
{
    public partial class Generic : ResourceDictionary
    {
        private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to merge your `ResourceDictionary` in the `App.Xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CustomCalc;component/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem but I had `x:Class` defined. Turned out the way I named it was wrong. The convention is `x:Class="NAMESPACE.CLASSNAME"`I never changed the name after renaming my files.

Answer (score 3):

In my case with **Visual Studio 2015** and a WPF project, the error went away after the Visual Studio restart.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had different namespaces for the XAML:

`<Window x:Class="NameSpace1.MyClass"`

and the code file:

```
namespace NameSpace2
{
    public partial class MyClass: Window
    {
        public WpfODAttributeQuery()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Just corrected the namespaces and the error got away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the XAML file (App.xaml to be specific) was in a Shared Project at the time I tried to create the event and got stuck for a few minutes with the error subject of this thread.

My solution was to exclude the XAML file along with its XAML.cs file from the Shared Project then linking (not copying !) it in each dependent platform project.

See the following GIF for a graphic visualization of the linking process:
[Linking files between projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1s0c.gif)

Source:
http://geertvanhorrik.com/2015/04/01/fix-for-wpf-images-and-shared-projects/

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by closing and reopening the `xaml` document causing the error (Visual Studio 2017). My `xaml` is also in a shared project.

If needed a restart to Visual Studio has helped me also.

Answer (score 0):

Currently running Xamarin Forms in VS 2017 Enterprise and had this issue.

In my case it only occurred when I tried to add an Event Handler to a newly defined xaml Button. Cancelling debugging and trying again fixed this.